# Xamarin Studio - How to output several projects to one directory

Tags: xamarin-studio

I want to build several projects from one solution (executable and class libraries) to one "output" directory. How do I do this? The only way I can see is using custom-created commands for the "After-Build" event which seems klunky!

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on the project settings, and under the build menu is an `Output" option which allows you to specify the output directory.